# How I can use the "for" with a variable and different numbers?

Tags: java

I want to create a for like this:

```
for(int i=-0.8;i<2;i+n){
...
}
```

I do have the error: error: not a statement.

Whats my mistake? Can I do it like this?

Thanks for help.

-Regards

ChrizZly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i=-0.8;i<2;i+n){
```

Here, `i+n` is not valid. You need to assign the new value to `i`, so it should be like this

```
for(int i=-0.8;i<2;i=i+n){
```

or

```
for(int i=-0.8;i<2;i+=n){
```

You also need to modify the type of `i` to `double`, as `int` doesnt have decimals.

```
for(double i=-0.8;i<2;i+=n){
```

Comment: `Double.compare(d1, d2)` should be used in the last for loop when `i` is `double`

Comment: Forgot about int doesn't have decimals.. Thanks

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande No. You should use `Double.compare` when checking for equality, in this case it's not needed. Look at the implementation and you'll notice this yourself

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande Look the JDK implementation for Double.compare here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EleRA.png

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=-0.8;
```

0.8 is a double value. Should not be assigned to `int`

`for(int i=0;i<2;i++)//to increment i by one`
or

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i+=n)//increment i by n
```

you can search for compound operators in java.

If you want to use double in loop, for the stopping condition you can use

```
for(double i = 0.0 ; Double.compare(i, n) > 0 ; i+=n)

Double.compare(d1, d2)   // is more precise for comparing double/float values
```

- returns the value 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2
- a value less than 0 if d1 is numerically less than d2
- a value greater than 0 if d1 is numerically greater than d2

Comment: actually seems correct, inclusive when `double` word was `decimal`, my suspect? it's just seconds later of first answer and after others... people make technical downvotes sometimes....

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a `double` value to an `int`. This is invalid. Use:

```
double i = -0.8
```

You are not modifying the counter variable (`i`) in the step section. `i+n` is a mathematical operation, not an assignment. Use:

```
i += n
```

The condition is OK

Final `for` loop:

```
for (double i = -0.8; i < 2; i += n){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem:

```
int i=-0.8 (Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int)
```

Second problem:

in order to have a correct for statement you have to use an assignment where you wrote `i+n`

This is a possible compiling snippet of code

```
    double n=10.0;
    for(double i=-0.8; i<2.0 ;i=i+n){
        ....    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make it 
    int i = 0;
or `double = -0.8;`
int i = -0.8 will be error because 0.8 is not integer. it double.
I hope you will get this.